# Cannot create empty spreadsheet Drive API

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-drive-android-api

I am using the sample code of [googledrive](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileWithCreatorActivity.java) and I am creating an empty file like:

```
MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
   .setMimeType(MIME_TYPE).build();

IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi.newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
   .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
   .setInitialDriveContents(null /*or result.getDriveContents()*/) //both same results
   .build(getGoogleApiClient());

startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

For `MIME_TYPE = "text/html"` the code works as expected `onActivityResult` I get `resultCode -> RESULT_OK` intent with extras the DriveId of the created file. And if I browse my Google Drive I see the created file.

But when I change the  `MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"` in order to create an empty Spreadsheet then the `resultCode -> RESULT_CANCELED` with null intent and no file is created.

Do I need any extra parameter for the spreadsheet? Why it's not created?

Documentation mentions that the Spreadsheet API cannot create a file but you can use the Drive API for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you cannot create/edit Google Docs files with GDAA. To do this you will have to use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

Comment: Any known 3rd party library for that? Or do I have to implement all the connectivity with the API? That is a huge task.

Comment: You can use the java client library so you don't have to implement it yourself. You will have to make handle Auth differently than when using the REST client library though. The following link should get you started https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android